# The System and the Measuring Gadget

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

In Quantum Mechanics the value of an observable results from the interaction between the "system" with the "Measuring gadget".

But when the experimenter[or the technologist concerned] is devising/constructing the gadget he has a view the "system" with its stand alone properties/attributes.It seems to be so.

But theory itself cannot ascribe the value of some observable to the system alone.
How does one explain this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some system in a [superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition) of states, then when your measuring gadget interacts with it it becomes [entangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) with the original system and it too is in a superposition of states. If you walk over to look at your measuring gadget you too become entangled and enter a superposition of states, and so on up to and including the journal you publish the results in.

In real life we don't see macroscopic objects, cats or otherwise, in a superposition of states, and the reason is generally considered to be [decoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoherence). The describes the interaction of a system with the rest of the universe and the loss of coherence that results. The rate at which a system decoheres increases with the complexity of the system, so while a superposition of states can be maintained for an atom or molecule, it is lost almost instantaneously for something the size and complexity of lab equipment, and your experiment returns a definite value for whatever you were looking at.

The largest system that has been observed in a superposition of states contains [about ten trillion atoms](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=quantum-microphone).

Comment: "Decoherence can be viewed as the loss of information from a system into the environment (often modeled as a heat bath),[2] since every system is loosely coupled with the energetic state of its surroundings."...from Wikipedia[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence]. When we talk of the "loss of information from a system" we seem to consider certain well defined stand alone properties of the system.This "leaked" information interacts with the evironment, the gadget being a part of it to produce the value of the measurement.

Comment: Information leaks out of the system----this information "leaked" is indicative of properties of the system $independent{\;} of{\;} the{\;} environment$ . The leaked information gets modified by interaction with the environment,the gadget being a part of it.Is it possible to eliminate the effect of the environment in the process of measurement?

Comment: In the last sentence of the previous comment I have tried to indicate at a mathematical/theoretical elimination of environmental effects to get to the stand alone properties of the system in a theoretical manner

Comment: You might want to ask this as a separate question. It is certainly possible to calculate the properties of an isolated system, and in fact that's what we normally do. The problem is that eventually a measurement is looked at by a human and we are part of the environment.

Comment: The comments to the Original Posting "The Lorentz transformations in the Micro-world" may be related to the issue at hand. Link: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18619/the-lorentz-transformations-in-the-micro-world